# removing objects from an array during a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to filter the results of an user search in my app to only show users who are NOT friends.  My friends table has 3 columns; f1 (userid of person who sent request), f2 (userid of friend who received request), and confirmed (boolean of true or false).  As you can see, @usersfiltered is the result of the search. Then the definition of the current user's friend is established.  Then I am trying to remove the friends from the search results.  This does not seem to be working but should be pretty straight forward.  I've tried delete (not good) and destroy.

```
def index

#THIS IS THE SEARCH RESULT

@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE?", "%#{params[:first_name]}%" )

#THIS IS DEFINING ROWS ON THE FRIEND TABLE THAT BELONG TO CURRENT USER

@confirmedfriends = Friend.where(:confirmed => true)
friendsapproved = @confirmedfriends.where(:f2 => current_user.id)
friendsrequestedapproved = @confirmedfriends.where(:f1 => current_user.id)

#GOING THROUGH SEARCH RESULTS
@usersfiltered.each do |usersfiltered|

  if friendsapproved.present?
    friendsapproved.each do |fa|
      if usersfiltered.id == fa.f1
 #NEED TO REMOVE THIS FROM RESULTS HERE SOMEHOW
          usersfiltered.remove
      end
    end
  end
#SAME LOGIC
  if friendsrequestedapproved.present?
    friendsrequestedapproved.each do |fra|
      if usersfiltered.id == fra.f2
          usersfiltered.remove
      end
    end
  end

  end
```

end

Comment: Instead of `remove` try using `destroy`

Comment: won't that destroy the user?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would flip it around the other way. Take the logic that is loop-invariant out of the loop, which gives a good first-order simplification:

```
approved_ids = []
approved_ids = friendsapproved.map { |fa| fa.f1 } if friendsapproved.present?
approved_ids += friendsrequestedapproved.map { |fra| fra.f2 } if friendsrequestedapproved.present?
approved_ids.uniq!  # (May not be needed)
@usersfiltered.delete_if { |user| approved_ids.include? user.id }
```

This could probably be simplified further if `friendsapproved` and `friendsrequestedapproved` have been created separately strictly for the purpose of the deletions. You could generate a single `friendsapproval` list consisting of both and avoid unioning id sets above.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that there may be better ways to implement what you're doing, I think the specific problem you're facing is that in Rails 4, the `where` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` not an `Array`. While you can use `each` on a `Relation`, you cannot in general perform array operations.

However, you can convert a `Relation` to an `Array` with the `to_a` method as in:

```
@usersfiltered = User.where("first_name LIKE?", "%#{params[:first_name]}%" ).to_a
```

This would then allow you to do the following within your loop:

```
usersfiltered.delete(fa)
```